# Class does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have a data list user control where I inserted a hyperlink with this property:

> NavigateUrl='<%# MyLinkGen.ToFilm(Eval("fid").ToString()) %>'

MyLinkGen is a class, where I define the "ToFilm" method. According to this method, ToFilm("33") for example should generate the following link:

> /Catalog.aspx?FilmID=33.

When I run the project, I get this error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'MyLinkGen' does not exist in
>   the current context

Any ideas, please? What should I change? How can I include the class in the context? I'm fairly sure the class is correctly defined. Thanks a billion. Anna

Comment: @Anna T Please add the relevant code and markup in your post.

Comment: Thank you AVD! This was solved by putting the two files (.cs and .ascx - the ascx. referenced the .cs in this case) - into the same directory. I don't know of an alternative or the exact explanation.

Comment: The .cs is inside App_Code and it's defined like this: public static class MyLinkGen { ... } and the .ascx is inside UserControls and defined like this: namespace Cinemax.App_code
{
    public partial class FilmsList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {      .............    }
}

Answer (score 1):

You might need an 'import' reference directive.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyAppNamespace" %>
```

Comment: The class MyLinkGen is NOT inside of a namespace. So in this case, that is not necessary, Chris, is it? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I was using myLinkGen and MyLinkGen. I forgot that C# is case sensitive. The class is NOW recognised, but I get another error (see below):

Comment: If you are developing against the 'website' model and your class is in the App_Code folder, you should not have to use the import directive.

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'MyLinkGen' exists in both 'c:\Users\Anna\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4d5020a7\d97fd8db\assembly\dl3\c8625a02\a6576503_c93ccd01\Cinemax.DLL' and 'c:\Users\Anna\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4d5020a7\d97fd8db\App_Code.kikh0chl.dll'

Comment: I encountered this before and couldn't solve it by applying the most common suggestion, which is deleting the temporary files from "Temporary ASP.NET Files". Any ideas?

Comment: 'Clean' the solution, then perform a complete rebuild at the solution level.

Comment: The error message points to two "DLL" files being created - I didn't manually create any of them. So they are probably created automatically. Not sure what they contain. I'm guessing that perhaps one DLL should be created instead??

Comment: Looks like you may have 'copied' your code to the app_code directory?  If so, you could have left it in the Cinemax.DLL and added the namespace as I suggested.

Comment: Delete everything from `'c:\Users\Anna\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root` -> clean your solution -> rebuild your solution -> run it.

Comment: Same error, still. As for the App_Code directory, there is where the MyLinkGen class resides, indeed. Also, I have another directory called "UserControls" that contains a FilmsList.ascx file that references the MyLinkGen class like this: the NavigateUrl='<%# MyLinkGen.ToFilm(Eval("fid").ToString()) %>' .

Comment: Actually, when I just now moved the MyLinkGen from "App_code" to UserControls directory (where the .ascx file that references MyLinkGen resides), it worked! What is the explanation?? How can I get the project to run if I keep both files where they initially were?

Comment: It might be a partial class, which you split up into two areas.  When the two partials were brought back to the same namespace, it resolved the issue.  Can't really tell for sure without seeing all the code.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much Chris. I'm glad that the project is functional now, and it generates the links very nicely. I guess I will fully understand this example when I will have experience with namespaces and not only. I'm new for now. Have a great day! Anna